# Is there a way to view all the paths through a method in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm writing unit tests for a Java method which contains nested if statements. I want to write a test for each path through the method. However, I'm finding it hard work to identify all the paths.

Here's an example method through which there are three paths:

```java
public void myMethod(int i) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        System.out.println("foo");
    else {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            System.out.println("bar");
        else
            System.out.println("baz");
    }
}
```

For this method, I'd want an output something like:

1. `if (i % 2 == 0)` `->` `System.out.println("foo");`
2. `if (i % 2 == 0)` `->` `if (i % 3 == 0)` `->` `System.out.println("bar");`
3. `if (i % 2 == 0)` `->` `if (i % 3 == 0)` `->` `System.out.println("baz");`

Does a feature like this exist in IntelliJ IDEA? And if not, is there another tool that'll do the job?

Comment: You could run the test with coverage to see which paths you've already covered and which aren't covered yet.

Comment: You might also consider rewriting your code if it's that hard to interpret :)

Comment: The problem is that for complex code it's hard to determine all possible paths. You could use code coverage for unit tests to see which statements have been "visited" by your tests but you might not get all possible combinations covered by tests - that might be overkill anyway.

Comment: Btw, you should normally write tests based on what a piece of code is _expected_ to do (e.g. based on some specification) rather than on what the code is actually doing - unless you know that's all correct and you need the tests for regression purposes. If you base your tests on what the code is doing then they'd all be successful even if the code would actually contain bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Run the test with coverage (next to debug icon) then you can see what you have covered.